# Pasting textbox values to access database

Tags: c#, insert, database-connection

Now i get the problem at the try statement ( int count =insert.......). 
The compailer says(when i push the buton on the form to save the values in textboxes) that it Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.
code:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
       string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
     + "Data Source=C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\save.mdb";

        OleDbConnection empConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);


        string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO obroki_save "
                             + "([ID_uporabnika],[datum],[ID_zivila],[skupaj_kalorij]) "
                             + "VALUES (@ID_uporabnika,@datum,@ID_zivila,@skupaj_kalorij)";

        OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertStatement, empConnection);

        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID_uporabnika", OleDbType.Integer).Value = users.iDTextBox.Text;
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@datum", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID_zivila", OleDbType.Integer).Value = iDTextBox.Text;
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@skupaj_kalorij", OleDbType.Integer).Value = textBox1.Text;
        empConnection.Open();

        try
        {
           int count = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            empConnection.Close();
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
            textBox5.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@datum", OleDbType.Char).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

You're inserting a date as datatype Char, which looks wrong.

Comment: tnx for the answer, but still. i changed to date, dbdat other db___ and stil it  shows the same error

Comment: I notice that you also are not setting the length of the parameters, maybe part of the problem. Though I'd suggest that you amend your question to also show what datatype each of the fields are in the DB.

Comment: everything is long integer just datum is general date

Comment: Try changing the OleDbType of the other ones to BigInt rather than Char.

Comment: i changed everything to OleDbType.integer and datum to OleDbType.date and now i get an error at try statement: 
Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.What should i do now ?

Comment: Currently you're just sending in the Text member of the textboxes to the parameters. Convert these values to int first, you can see how here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx

Comment: so i should convert at lines insertCommand.Parameters.Add? or at the end (i tried to convert at the end ....=Convert.ToIn32(users.iDTextBox.Text);) it stil didn't work!

Comment: I'd thought something like: 
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID_uporabnika", OleDbType.Char).Value = Convert.ToIn32(users.iDTextBox.Text));

Comment: you might want to update your question to add the updated sample, it's a bit confusing with these comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your data types: textbox.value hold a string and to convert it, you can use int.Parse.

```
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID_zivila", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(iDTextBox.Text);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@skupaj_kalorij", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```